# Combining Text and Math Symbols in Plot Title

Tags: r

I want to combine text and math symbols in "main" title of my histogram. I've tried using both `bquote()` and `expression()` but doesn't seem to work. Below is what I'm trying to do. I want both R^2 and sigma to appear as symbols in my main title if possible.

```
hist(R2_sig_3, col="lightskyblue", border="royalblue", xlab=expression(R^2),
     main=bquote(~R^2 "values \nfor sigma=10"))
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 3):

You were nearly there. Does this work?

This includes plotmath for the Greek rendition of sigma and the new line:

```r
hist(iris$Sepal.Length,
     col="lightskyblue",
     border="royalblue",
     xlab = expression(R^2),
     main = expression(~R^2~atop(values~"for",~sigma~"="~10)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Can we make sigma into a symbol too?

Comment: Just added this option!